# Parsing resource Visual Studio .rc file with the sed command

Tags: bash, shell, sed, rc

How can i use sed for pase .rc file? And I need get from resource file blocks STRINGTABLE

```
...

STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
    IDS_ID101    "String1"
    IDS_ID102    "String2"
END

...
```

and result need output to str_file.h

```
std::map<int, std::string> m = {
    {IDS_ID101, "String1"},
    {IDS_ID102, "String2"},
};
```

How do I write a command in sed so that I can get this result?

I write this command, but this not help me

```
sed '/^BEGIN$/{N;N;s/BEGIN\(.*\)END/replaced \1/}/g' ${RC_FILE} > test_rc.h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` seems more fit for this task than `sed`:

```bash
awk '
    /^STRINGTABLE/ {
        in_block = 1
        print "std::map<int, std::string> m = {"
        next
    }
    in_block && /^END/ {
        in_block = 0
        print "};"
        next
    }
    in_block && match($0,/".*"/) {
        print "    {" $1 ", " substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) "},"
    }
' "$RC_FILE" > test_rc.h
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '/STRINGTABLE/{
         :a;N;/\nEND/!ba
         s/.*BEGIN(\s+)(\S+)\s+(\S+)(\s+)(\S+)\s+(\S+).*/std::map<int, std::string> m = {\1{\2, \3},\4{\5, \6},\n};/p
         }' file
```

Gather up lines between `STRINGTABLE` and `END` and then using pattern matching and back references, format the output as required.